# VBA DASL Filters / PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID Search

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I'm attempting to implement a VBA Module within Outlook (v2038) that will allow you to search your mailbox using the Internet Message ID of a message. I've stumbled my way across the internet on how to accomplish this, and found two promising methods; but they are failing to return results when tested with present message's internet message IDs. I'm hoping to get someone with expertise on the matter to aid me in this.

[Module 1](https://superuser.com/questions/1351140/searching-by-message-id-in-outlook): (This will allow you select a specific folder/subfolder and search by msgID within Outlook)

```
Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
    If SearchObject.Tag = "MessageId" Then
        Set Results = SearchObject.Results
        MsgBox "Message-ID search complete. " & Results.Count & " result(s) found."
        For i = 1 To Results.Count
            Results.Item(i).Display
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub SearchMessageId()
    Set Folder = Session.PickFolder
    If Not Folder Is Nothing Then
        r = MsgBox("Include subfolders?", vbYesNoCancel, "Search by Message-ID")
        If r <> vbCancel Then
            MessageId = InputBox("Message-ID:")
            If MessageId <> "" Then
                Application.AdvancedSearch "'" & Folder.FolderPath & "'", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F = '" & MessageId & "'", r = vbYes, "MessageId"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[Module 2:](https://www.youtube.com/@WiseOwlTutorials) (This will search your Default Folder on Outlook by msgID within VBA)

```
Sub UseDASLFilters()

    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim filterString As String
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    filterString = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F"" = '<example@pr.internet.message.id>' "
    
    For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict(filterString)
    
        If i.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set mi = i
            
            Debug.Print mi.SenderEmailAddress, mi.Subject, mi.ReceivedTime
        
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

From the information I could gather, the MAPI property tag for PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID should be 0x1035001F, 0x1035001E, or &H1035001E.

When using each proptag mentioned within Module2, no results were returned, so perhaps I need to define [Set i = Nothing] and/or [Dim '' as FileSystemObject] [Set '' = CreateObject()]...

(EDIT: MsgID must be closed with "<>")

Comment: Are you sure the message id is what you have in the query? Is it surrounded by `<` and `>`? Take a look at an existing message with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) to see whether the id is right.